# How to refresh the page by sending the data?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function order_completed($puja_order_id,$user_id)
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('admin_login') != 1)
    redirect(site_url().'/admin/login', 'refresh');
    $page_data['page_name']     = 'completed_events';
    $page_data['page_title']    = 'Completed Events';
    $page_data['comp_events']   = $this->crud_model->get_puja_orders_status_of_puja_completed();

    $datetime   = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
    $data = array(
            'status_of_puja'            => 'COMPLETED',
            'datetime'                  => $datetime
    );
    $this->db->where('puja_order_id',$puja_order_id);
    $this->db->where('user_id',$user_id);
    $result = $this->db->update('puja_orders',$data);   
    if ($result)
    $this->load->view('admin/completed_events',$page_data);
}
```

How can I refresh the page using the code and by sending the page_data also?
Every thing was going perfect, but after sending the data into that page, I need to refresh the page manually.
This should not happen. The page should refresh itself.
When I use redirect, then, how to send the page_data?

Comment: Store your array in `flashdata` and `redirect` and `access` :)

Comment: Try to use ajax call

Comment: You can write `refresh` code in your view file too;

Answer (score 0):

Set your data to flashdata :

> https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata

and then redirect to your page like `redirect('admin/completed_events','refresh')`

and after that in your view setup something that will check if flashdata is set and show it

Comment: If you use flash data as well as refresh on redirect it will clear the flashdata.

Comment: No,flash will stay for 1 refresh, so when you set data and refresh it will be there, but if you refresh again it is gone. You can set flashdata to last longer if you want, but if I understand your code, you are sending "COMPLETED" I don't think you need to send that more than 1 time ?